# How can I bind a text label to the selected option value of a dropdownlist in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

Is there an easy way to tell knockout to bind the selected value of a drop down list (not the id, the label) to another field? I have a moderately complicated UI and I would like a clean way to hook not only the id but the label of the option up to a field when it changes.

Something like:

```
 <select data-bind="options: dropDownLists.Region,optionsText:'RegionName',optionsValue:'RegionId',value:regionFilterId,label:regionFilterName" >
```

Where the label binding does the same thing as the value binding, but with the label of the option. I suspect I will need a custom binding, but I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Do you need the value of the `<option>` elements to be correctly set to the ID? (e.g. because the user may submit that form at some point)

Comment: No, I have the ID bound correctly to the corresponding model variable. The issue is I have a UI which allows the user to arbitrarily switch from drop down lists to text labels, and I want the text label to update if the drop down list has changed in case the user switches back. Does that make sense? Both the ID and the Display value are part of the model, I want to be able to bind both to the drop down list, not just the ID.

Comment: Anybody who lands here might want to check out the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166504/knockout-bind-text-label-to-dropdown-value-selected-option-text?rq=1 also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I've understood your requirements correctly, but if you don't care about the HTML, why not go with this:

```
<select data-bind="options: dropDownLists.Region,optionsText:'RegionName',value:regionFilter"></select>
```

The "optionsValue" binding is not used, so the "value" binding updates the observable no with only the ID, but with the full object. That makes it easy to write two computed observables, that return ID and Name of the selected region:

```
self.regionFilter = ko.observable();

self.regionFilterId = ko.computed(function() {
    var region = self.regionFilter();
    if (region) return region.RegionId;
});

self.regionFilterName = ko.computed(function() {
    var region = self.regionFilter();
    if (region) return region.RegionName;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VA7aF/

Comment: I hadn't thought about it this way, this should work for me, assuming I can easily keep the underlying Id on my model updated properly.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use subscribe:

```
self.regionFilter = ko.observable();
self.regionFilterId  = ko.observable();
self.regionFilterName = ko.observable();

self.regionFilter.subscribe(function(region) {
    self.regionFilterId(region.RegionId());
    self.regionFilterId(region.RegionName());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way suggested above would have me create a computed value for every ID/Name pair that I had in my model.

I wrote a custom binding, that supports this.  So now, I can just pass in my Object and get the 'Name' field.

Hope this helps:

HTML Binding:

```
<span>Agency: </span><span data-bind="keyvalue:Agency,data:'Name'"></span>
```

HTML Select:

```
<select id="selectAgency" data-bind="options: $root.agencies,optionsText: 'Name',optionsValue: function(item){return item;}, optionsCaption: 'Agency', value: Agency"></select>
```

JavaScript

```
ko.bindingHandlers.keyvalue = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var field = allBindings.data;
        if (value() !== undefined) {
            $(element).text(value()[field]);
        }
    }
};
```