# knockout bind text label to dropdown value selected option text

Tags: data-binding, drop-down-menu, knockout.js

Is there a simple way to bind the textbox of a div to change based on the text value of the selected option in a dropdown on the same page?

```
<div data-bind="text: dropdownValue"></div>
<select>
  <option value="1">Value1</option>
  <option value="2">Value2</option>
</select>
```

Please note, I don't want to put the values into the select element using javascript.  I'd like to bind to the value straight from the HTML.  I can also include jQuery to make it work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I was looking for similar functionality in something I was throwing together yesterday and couldn't find it, so I ended up just changing what I was storing in the value attributes. Sometimes that's the simplest solution.

Here's a quick and kind of ugly solution to the problem using jQuery:

#### HTML

```
<div data-bind="text: dropdownText"></div>
<select data-bind="value: dropdownValue" id="dropdown">
  <option value="1">Value1</option>
  <option value="2">Value2</option>
</select>
```

#### JS

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.dropdownValue = ko.observable();
    this.dropdownText = ko.computed(function() {
        return $("#dropdown option[value='" + self.dropdownValue() + "']").text();
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/5PkBF/

If you were looking to do this in multiple places, it'd probably be best to write a custom binding, e.g.:

#### HTML

```
<div data-bind="text: dropdownValue"></div>
<select data-bind="selectedText: dropdownValue">
  <option value="1">Value1</option>
  <option value="2">Value2</option>
</select>
```

#### JS

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selectedText = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        value($("option:selected", element).text());

        $(element).change(function() {
            value($("option:selected", this).text());
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $("option", element).filter(function(i, el) { return $(el).text() === value; }).prop("selected", "selected");
    }
};

function ViewModel() {
    this.dropdownValue = ko.observable();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/5PkBF/1/

Comment: The problem I was having is that I was using the protectedObservable pattern here, which was causing problems.  http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html -- Still not able to get it working using this htough.

Comment: I believe you have a bug in the filter, should be `function(index, el)`

Comment: Thanks, @fearofawhackplanet, you're absolutely right. Here's an updated an example that actually updates both ways: http://jsfiddle.net/5PkBF/205/.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I implemented a similar feature.  I had an observable defined in my model called 'dropDownValue'.  I also had an observable array called 'dropDownValues'.  My HTML looked something like:

```
<span data-bind="text: dropDownValue"></span>
<select data-bind="options: dropDownValues, optionsValue: 'FieldText', optionsText: 'FieldText', value: dropDownValue"></select>
```

Note that I used the same field for optionValues and optionsText (not sure optionsText is really needed in this case).  In my particular app 'dropDownValue' was pre-populated elsewhere, so when I opened a dialog box with the above select in it I wanted it to default to the previously populated value, and also bind it so that if the user changed it, I could reflect that change back in the database.