# show selected item from dropdown as text binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I simply create a select list binding as following

```
<select id="listingstatus"   data-bind="options: ListingTypeArrary, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', selectedOptions: ListingType" ></select>
```

**My Model**

```
var listArray = JSON.parse([{
    "Selected": false,
    "Text": "Commercial",
    "Value": "4"
}, {
    "Selected": false,
    "Text": "Residential",
    "Value": "5"
}]);
self.ListingTypeArrary = ko.observableArray();
$.each(listArray, function (index, value) {

    var obj = {};
    obj["Text"] = value.Text;
    obj["Value"] = value.Value;
    self.ListingTypeArrary.push(obj);

});

self.ListingType = ko.observable('@Model.ListingTypeId'); // @Model.ListingTypeId will be equals to 5
```

after doing this knockout render my dropdown/selectlist perfectly . But i have a requirement that i don't have to show dropdown i just need to show selected item as text . Any one can help me ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: so you need span instead of dropdown?

Comment: possible duplicate of [knockout bind text label to dropdown value selected option text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166504/knockout-bind-text-label-to-dropdown-value-selected-option-text)

Comment: @ebramtharwat  I tried that but an error occurs and its says :Unhandled exception at line 5, column 28 in http://localhost:30596/scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: options binding applies only to SELECT elements

Comment: @user2413182 as the errer says: you can't use **options** binding with text. You can only use it with **select**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, once a user has made a selection, you want the `<select>` to disappear, and a textual label to appear in its place.

You will have to compute that label based on the selected `Value`, then display either the `<select>` or a text label, conditionally.

## HTML

```
<!-- ko ifnot: SelectedListingText -->
<select id="listingstatus" data-bind="
    options: ListingTypeArray,
    optionsText: 'Text',
    optionsValue: 'Value',
    value: ListingType"></select>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: SelectedListingText -->
<span data-bind="text: SelectedListingText"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

## Javascript

### Original Data

```
var listArray = [
  {
    "Selected": false,
    "Text": "Commercial",
    "Value": "4"
  },
  {
    "Selected": false,
    "Text": "Residential",
    "Value": "5"
  }
];
```

### Options for the select

```
// Synthesize the listing type array for the select
ListingTypeArray = ko.observableArray([{ Text: 'Choose one', Value: null }]);
$.each(listArray, function (index, value) {
    var obj = {};
    obj["Text"] = value.Text;
    obj["Value"] = value.Value;
    ListingTypeArray.push(obj);
});
```

### Storage for the selected option

```
// The chosen listing type
ListingType = ko.observable();
```

### The computed text label

```
// Compute the label text based on the selected Value
SelectedListingText = ko.computed(function () {
  type = ListingType();
  if(!type) return;

  // Find the text associated with this type
  var foundListingTypeName;
  $.each(listArray, function (index, listingType) {
    if(listingType.Value == type) {
      foundListingTypeName = listingType.Text;
      return false;
    }
  });

  return foundListingTypeName;
});
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/steveluscher/rmnMt/

Comment: Interesting, I thought he was asking for something like a [typeahead](http://billpull.github.io/knockout-bootstrap/#typeahead)