# How to get the text of selected option in knockout and use it in the url of ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to implement cascading dropdowns, options loaded by making AJAX call to a SharePoint list. Is there any way I can grab the text of the selected option and use it in the url of another AJAX. I have tried this:[knockout bind text label to dropdown value selected option text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166504/knockout-bind-text-label-to-dropdown-value-selected-option-text). Doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

My HTML:
First dropdown:

```
<select id="dropdown "class="form-control" data-bind="options: titles,event:{ change: loadEmployees}">
```

AJAX URL of second dropdown:

```
url: Url + "/items?$filter=(Title eq " + selectedOption + ")",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than binding to the change event, you should bind the value and then use a subscription to that observable.

```
<select id="dropdown "class="form-control" data-bind="options: titles, value: selectedTitle">
```

In your viewmodel:

```
this.selectedTitle = ko.observable();

selectedTitle.subscribe(function(value) {
    // load via ajax
});
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, I'm new to knockout.js. I will be using more of subscription now. Thanks a bunch.